# Dynamic Tag Management - Storing

Tags: adobe-analytics

We're in the process of moving to DTM implementation. We have several variables that are being defined on page. I understand I can make these variables available in DTM through data elements. Can I simply set up a data elem

So set data elements

```
%prop1% = s.prop1
%prop2% = s.prop2
etc
```

And then under global rules set

```
s.prop1 = %s.prop1%
s.prop2 = %s.prop2% 
etc
```

for every single evar, sprop, event, product so they populate whenever they are set on a particular page. Good idea or terrible idea? It seems like a pretty bulky approach which raises some alarm bells. Another option would be to write something that pushes everything to the datalayer, but that seems like essentially the same approach with a redundant step when they can be grabbed directly.

Basically I want DTM to access any and all variables that are currently being set with on-page code, and my understanding is that in order to do that they must be stored in a data element first. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving from a legacy s_code implementation to DTM, it is a good best practice to remove all existing "on page" code (including the reference to the s_code file) and create a "data layer" that contains the data from the eVars and props on the page. Then DTM can reference the object on the page and you can create data elements that map to variables.

Here's an example of a data layer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

DDO = {} // Data Layer Object Created
DDO.specVersion = "1.0";
DDO.pageData = {
"pageName":"My Page Name",
"pageSiteSection":"Home",
"pageType":"Section Front",
"pageHier":"DTM Test|Home|Section Front"
},
 DDO.siteData = {
"siteCountry":"us",
 "siteRegion":"unknown",
 "siteLanguage":"en",
 "siteFormat":"Desktop"
}

</script>
```

The next step would be to create data elements that directly reference the values in the object. For example, if I wanted to create a data element that mapped to the page name element in my data layer I would do the following in DTM:

- Create a new data element called "pageName"
- Select the type as "JS Object"
- In the path field I will reference the path to the page name in my data layer example above - DDO.pageData.pageName
- Save the data element

Now this data element can be referenced in any variable field within any rule by simply typing a '%'. DTM will find any existing data elements and you can select them.

I also wrote about a simple script you can add to your implementation to help with your data layer validation.[Validate your DTM Data Layer with this simple script](http://www.searchdiscovery.com/blog/validating-your-adobe-dtm-data-layer-with-this-simple-script/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful - thanks. My followup question to this is regarding the approach for setting this up in DTM so it sets any and all variables that appear in the data layer? Do you create a data element for every single variable, and then set every variable to populate with those elements globally? I.e. in the DTM Adobe Analytics configuration, map every single variable to the corresponding data element so it populates whenever it is present in the data layer? Is there a best practice for grabbing and setting everything that appears in the data layer on every page? Thanks again!

Comment: @MaximusDecimusMeridius 

First thing is to create a data element for each data dimension in the data layer. The next thing is to determine which of those data elements need to be set on every page load and then set them globally by using the "Global Variables" section in the AA tool config or adding them to a global page load rule. I prefer the global page load rule approach for flexibility but using the Global Variables section isn't a bad place to start.

Comment: OK global pageload rule is something I'd lean toward as well. I guess my question is, since we have different events firing on pretty much every single page (or at least a very large number of them) can you do this as a catch-all approach. That is, set every single variable to load as a global variable on pageload, but only the ones that contain values (the ones that happen to be set on a particular page and therefore populate their respective data element) will get passed to AA?

Comment: if your events aren't considered global (set on every page) one option is to   create page load rules for each specific use case. That way you can set conditions ( based on URL, query params, etc) for when the unique events should fire.

Comment: Thanks. Issue with this is, there's a huge amount of URLs with different variables set so this would be a very big undertaking. This is why I want to look in to a catch-all approach, or at least have a strong motivation why one can't be used (to motivate the time setting up specific rules). Do you know if the catch-all approach I'm suggesting would work in practice, or are there limitations that would make this a bad idea? Thanks

Comment: Sound like your "catch all" would be to use a global page load rule and set variables based on certain conditions.

Comment: No, it would be to set every single variable equal to the corresponding data element. So first define the data elements

%prop1% = s.prop1
%prop2% = s.prop2
etc

and then set as a global rule

s.prop1 = %s.prop1%
s.prop2 = %s.prop2% 
etc

The plan here being that whenever a variable actually has a value set it will be catpured in the data element and set by DTM, but if it doesn't it will simply be ignored

Comment: With a global rule, you can always set your variables if a data element has a value. Otherwise, DTM will return a value set to null (or %data_element_name%
You can choose to have DTM return null (blank) if data elements are not set by selecting "Return empty string for undefined Data Elements" in your property configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I use this spec for setting up data layers: [Data Layer Standard](http://www.w3.org/2013/12/ceddl-201312.pdf)

We create data elements for each key that we use from the standard data layer. For example, page name is stored here

```
digitalData.page.pageInfo.pageName
```

We create a data element and standardize the names to this format "page.pageInfo.pageName"
Within each variable field, you access it with the %page.pageInfo.pageName% notation. Also, within javascript of rule tags, you can use this:

```
_satellite.getVar('page.pageInfo.pageName')
```

It's a bit unwieldy at times but it allows you to separate the development of the data layer and tag manager tags completely.

One thing to note, make sure your data layer is complete and loaded before you call the satellite library.